# How can I remove a specified version of project in Hg?

Tags: mercurial, branch

I want to ask a question about Hg.

[image]

You can see the picture that there is a branch from **196** to **199**, and now I want to remove the branch in the server version and use the **195** as the newest version, could you please tell me how to do that?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 196:199 was already pushed to remote, you can't delete this branch (check `hg out` or phases of these revisions)

If 196:199 are pure local, you can just simply [`hg strip`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension) not needed anymore anonymous branch

Anyway, you can:

1. [Dummy merge](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge) r199 into r195 and continue work
2. Forget about branch, and continue your work from 195 (first push with new child-commit of 195 will require `-f` due to new head in branch)

Comment: This seems so clearly a duplicate (many potential candidates IMO)

Comment: Thank you so much. I did it by a workaround, first, revert to some previous stable version, edit some file and forcely push the changes to the server to cover the backout version.